# How to find memory leaks in vue js project? Does Vue js handle those leaks on its own?

Tags: vue.js, memory-leaks

I have tried finding memory leaks in my vue app. I have used chrome dev tools memory heap snap shot for that. But I was not able to find any. I tried looking for tutorials or videos on youtube and google. But most of them are explaining it using Native JS. Even in official documentation of Vue, they have explained it using third party library. Now, I am not sure whether my app has memory leaks or not.

Is there any good resources which I can refer for it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, profiling tools are only help you to monitor & decide if you app got memory leaks or not. It cannot throw to your face the simple result like yes or no, but it allow you to see the bigger picture of your app performance.

And following that stats you can see the problem with your app, which usually happens over time (that mean you have to monitor it, not just run the profiling tool then check the result).

Vue is just a framework/library that written in JS. So there is no magical tools to tell you exactly what's wrong with your own code.

There are some tools for Vue to monitor the render process like [this one](https://github.com/kwai-explore/why-did-you-update).
You can see how your app re-render & why does it so. Depends on your code logic you can decide which one should only render once & optimize that part. That will prevent the memleak as well.

Comment: Can you give some examples which can cause memory leaks in vue js?

Comment: @AnujDeep Not in Vue, that's your coding skill. Vue can't cause memleak by itself

Answer (score 0):

Anuj memory leak is a much wider topic than one single language. There are examples using library's in documentation because generally, the third-party package which doesn't take care of memory usage leads to memory leaks we should take care of that.
Check out this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTJ-P9dcC1c) to detect memory leaks in your projects.

Answer (score 0):

[Fuite](https://github.com/nolanlawson/fuite/) is a great tool to find memory leaks. They have a nice [introductory video](https://youtu.be/H0BHL2lo89M) linked in their readme as well. Basically it crawls your app for internal links, and then repeatedly visits them (for example from `/` to `about`, then the native "Back" navigation, then repeats `N` number of times). After each visit, it checks if any event listeners or DOM nodes were left detached. You'll get a nice readable report by the end of it.

You can run it from the CLI `npx fuite http://localhost:8080` or if you have authentication guards or some custom interactions you'd like to define, then you can create "scenarios" for Fuite to go through.

Here's a simple custom scenario, that extends the fuite default scenario, by adding logging in. It then dumps the results into a JSON file. Make sure you've got the `logs` directory created beforehand. You'd also need to install `fuite` first, for example:

```bash
mkdir fuite-test && cd fuite-test
npm init -y 
npm i -D fuite
```

Now create a `fuite.mjs` file:

```js
import { defaultScenario, findLeaks } from 'fuite'
import fs from 'fs'

const domain = 'http://localhost:8080'
const myScenario = {
  ...defaultScenario,
  async setup(page) {
    let url = await page.url()

    if (!url.endsWith('login')) return

    // Run login code only if we're at /login
    await page.type('input[type=email]', 'email@example.com')
    await page.type('input[type=password]', 'password')
    await page.click('button[type=submit]')
  },
}

let log = []

for await (const result of findLeaks(domain, {
  scenario: myScenario,
  iterations: 5,
  heapsnapshot: false,
  debug: process.env.DEBUG || false,
  progress: true,
  browserArgs: ['--use-fake-device-for-media-stream']
})) {
  const entry = JSON.stringify(result, null, 2)
  // If you want, you can also print the logs while the scanner runs:
  // console.log(entry)
  log.push(entry)
}

console.info('Fuite scan finished:', log.length)

const filename = `fuite.${Date.now()}.json`
console.info('Dumping log file:', filename)
fs.writeFileSync(`logs/${filename}`, JSON.stringify(log, null, 2))
```

And you can run it with `node fuite.mjs`.

**NOTE**: If you have a large application with lots of links, you'd be better off to stream to the log/JSON file with `writeStream`, I'm a little lazy in my example here, so this could be slow for you.